# In C++, how to compute the mean of a vector of integers using a vector view and gsl_stats_mean?

Tags: c++, vector, gsl

my program manipulates **STL vectors of integers** but, from time to time, I need to calculate a few statistics on them. Therefore I use the **GSL functions**. To avoid copying the STL vector into a GSL vector, I create a **GSL vector view**, and give it to the GSL functions, as in this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  vector<int> stl_v;
  for( int i=0; i<5; ++i )
    stl_v.push_back( i );

  gsl_vector_int_const_view gsl_v = gsl_vector_int_const_view_array( &stl_v[0], stl_v.size() );

  for( int i=0; i<stl_v.size(); ++i )
    cout << "gsl_v_" << i << "=" << gsl_vector_int_get( &gsl_v.vector, i ) << endl;

  cout << "mean=" << gsl_stats_mean( (double*) gsl_v.vector.data, 1, stl_v.size() ) << endl;
}
```

Once compiled (gcc -lstdc++ -lgsl -lgslcblas test.cpp), this code outputs this:

```
gsl_v_0=0
gsl_v_1=1
gsl_v_2=2
gsl_v_3=3
gsl_v_4=4
mean=5.73266e-310
```

The vector view is properly created but I don't understand why the mean is wrong (it should be equal to 10/5=2). Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for a well-asked first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the integer statistics functions:

```
cout << "mean=" << gsl_stats_int_mean( gsl_v.vector.data, 1, stl_v.size() ) << endl;
```

Note the `gsl_stats_int_mean` instead of `gsl_stats_mean`.

Answer (score 4):

The cast to `double*` is very suspicious.

Any time you are tempted to use a cast, think again.  Then look for a way to do it without a cast (maybe by introducing a temporary variable if the conversion is implicit).  Then think a third time before you cast.

Since the memory region does not actually contain `double` values, the code is simply interpreting the bit patterns there as if they represented doubles, with predictably undesired effects.  Casting an `int*` to `double*` is VERY different from casting each element of the array.

Comment: Ok, from now on I will be more cautious with cast. Mark B also proposed a solution with a temporary vector, but does this mean that my initial vector has to be copied temporarily? What if this vector is very big?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing a lot of statistics considerably more complex than the mean, I'd ignore gsl and just use standard algorithms:

```
double mean = std::accumulate(stl_v.begin(), stl_v.end(), 0.0) / stl_v.size();
```

When/if using a statistical library is justified, your first choice should probably be to look for something else that's better designed (e.g., Boost Accumulators).

If you decide, for whatever reason, that you really need to use gsl, it looks like you'll have to copy your array of `int`s to an array of `double`s first, then use gsl on the result. This is obvious quite inefficient, especially if you're dealing with a lot of data -- thus the previous advice to use something else instead.

Comment: I'm writing a simulator, thus I need a RNG as well as functions to compute mean, var, sd, quantiles, and so on. That's why I would like to keep using the GSL, and not use std::accumulate.

Comment: @wfoolhill: The standard library already provides PRNG, and Boost accumulators (among many others) can compute all the functions you've mentioned -- much more cleanly than gsl even hopes to.

Comment: I don't know Boost, thus following your advice, I had a quick look at the documentation of Boost.Accumulator. It seems indeed very powerful but I don't think I need all its functionalities. I have all I need with the GSL up to now.

Comment: @wfoolhill: Everything you need other than working, of course. And even if you fix that, it's still only "other than working well."

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not familiar with GSL, the expression `(double*) gsl_v.vector.data` looks extremely suspicious.  Are you sure it's correct to `reinterpret_cast` that pointer to get `double` data?

Answer (score 1):

Casting to `double*` is messing up your data. It is not converting data into `double`, but just using `int` binary data as `double`

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Mean-and-standard-deviation-and-variance.html the `gsl_stats_mean` function takes an array of `double`. You're taking a `vector` of int and telling it to use the raw bytes as `double` which isn't going to work right.

You'll need to set up a temporary `vector` of double to pass in:

```
// Assumes that there's at least one item in stl_v.
std::vector<double> tempForStats(stl_v.begin(), stl_v.end());
gsl_stats_mean(&tempForStats[0], 1, tempForStats.size());
```

EDIT: You could also use standard library algorithms to do the int mean yourself:

```
// Assumes that there's at least one item in stl_v.
double total = std::accumulate(stl_v.begin(), stl_v.end(), 0);
double mean = total / stl_v.size();
```

Comment: Thanks, but by using a vector view, I wanted to avoid a temporary vector because, if the initial vector is very big, I will loose time copying it into a temporary one... Or is "tempForStats(stl_v.begin(), stl_v.end());" very efficient?