# column vector with row means -- with std::accumulate?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, mean, accumulate

In an effort to be as lazy as possible I read in a matrix as

```
vector< vector<double> > data ( rows, vector<double> ( columns ) );
```

and try to use as many STL goodies as I can.

One thing I need to do next is to compute the row means. In C-style programming that would be

```
vector<double> rowmeans( data.size() );
for ( int i=0; i<data.size(); i++ )
    for ( int j=0; j<data[i].size(); j++ )
        rowmeans[i] += data[i][j]/data[i].size();
```

In [In C++, how to compute the mean of a vector of integers using a vector view and gsl_stats_mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852954) it is explained that for a vector of numbers you can compute a vector mean in one line without calling the size() operator at every step:

```
double mean = std::accumulate(stl_v.begin(), stl_v.end(), 0.0) / stl_v.size();
```

Is it possible to use these iterators over a vector of vectors? An intermediate form is

```
vector<double> rowmeans( rows );
    for ( int i=0; i<data.size(); i++ )
        rowmeans[i] = std::accumulate(data[i].begin(), data[i].end(), 0.0) / data[i].size();
```

already 1 line gone! but using STL functions is it possible to get rid of the [i] index as well? (on the top level it's just a matter of collecting the row means).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), rowmeans.begin(),
    [](std::vector<double> const& d) {
        return std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0.0) / d.size();
    });
```

Although, my personal style would involve a named lambda or function, because I would find that more self-documenting:

```
auto Mean = [](std::vector<double> const& d) { return std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0.0) / d.size(); };
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), rowmeans.begin(), Mean);
```

Comment: That's what I wish I had thought about. +1

Comment: Using the 1st version (after some reading up on things I may switch to #2) in https://github.com/amwink/bias/blob/master/cpp/fastecm/fastecm.cpp -- thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using `boost::numeric::ublas` however (if it's an option):

```
matrix<double> m(rows,columns);
double mean = accumulate(m.data().begin(),m.data().end(),0,std::max<double>) / (rows * columns);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did like the one with for_each posted earlier as well though. Just for the lack of loop counters