# computing column sums of matrix vector<vector<double> > with iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, mean, accumulate

In a previous post [column vector with row means -- with std::accumulate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915602) I asked if it was possible, using STL functionality, to compute row means of a matrix

```
vector< vector<double> > data ( rows, vector<double> ( columns ) );
```

The top answer by @benjaminlindley is not only just what I was looking for, it is a thing of beauty. Forever hopeful I thought it would be as easy to compute column means, so an STL equivalent of

```
vector<double> colmeans( data[0].size() );
    for ( int i=0; i<data.size(); i++ )
        for ( int j=0; j<data[i].size(); j++ )            
            colmeans[j] += data[i][j]/data.size();
```

where the mean is not computed inside each `vector<double>`, but across the same index in all the vectors:

```
colmeans[0]       == ( data[0][0] + data[1][0] + ... data[rows][0] ) / rows
colmeans[1]       == ( data[0][1] + data[1][1] + ... data[rows][1] ) / rows
colmeans[2]       == ( data[0][2] + data[1][2] + ... data[rows][2] ) / rows
...
colmeans[columns] == ( data[0]   [columns] + 
                       data[1]   [columns] + 
                       ... 
                       data[rows][columns] ) / rows
```

It turns out to be quite different -- accumulate does not want to work on vectors of vectors. Is it somehow possible using accumulate with the `[]` operator? I cannot even come up with an intermediate form (to get rid of eather the `for i` or `for j` loop) which does not seem right.

Something with `accumulate` and the `[]` operator? Or `bind`?

Comment: If you think that Benjamin's anwser is good (which, BTW, it is) you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: honestly the hardest part of this will be the potential short-vector in your outer vector-of-vectors. Tis the basic problem when using `vector<vector<type>>`. There is no guarantee that each inner vector is the same size (except, of course by assuming it in your own code, which is populating this thing in the first place). This is not a problem when finding row-means, since you don't really care how many  columns there are.

Comment: so @WhozCraig are you saying it is a problem when finding column-means? BTW the guarantee that the inner vector sizes are the same is met, this does not change after initialisation -- `data` is basically a matrix of `rows` x `columns`

Comment: @alle_meije What I was saying was the data model chosen (vector of vectors) *allows* for the unexpected possibility of any given row not necessarily having the same column count as the other rows. It is a data model issue, not a matrix issue. So long as you enforce each row has the same column count in-code (as commented) it should be ok.

Comment: @WhozCraih I do know those for-loops are OK, but I don't know if (and how) the syntax of (I guess) accumulate allows for accessing indices / subsequent elements in sub-arrays. What I think I need to do is let an iterator access index 0 of every row vector (for the first element), index 1 of every row (for the next element), et cetera. I am not sure how that part of the syntax works.

Comment: To get `std::accumulate` to work for this purpose, you'd have to implement your own special iterator which jumps across vectors, and that would be a lot more work than simply using the for loop.  You might be able to find a simple solution in an external library, like boost, but not in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLindley, that is clear -- if a bit disappointing. It is probably best to move back, for consistency's sake, to for loops for the whole lot --also the row means, despite the beauty of your STL solution. Oh the benefits of contiguous storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something I came up with, using `for_each` and `transform`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> data { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3}, {1,2,3} };

std::vector<double> colsums( data[0].size() ); // initialize the size
                                                // to number of columns

std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(),

    [&](const std::vector<double>& row)
    {
        // Use transform overload that takes two input ranges.
        // Note that colsums is the second input range as well as the output range.
        // We take each element of the row and add it to the corresponding
        // element of colsums vector:
        std::transform(row.begin(), row.end(), colsums.begin(), colsums.begin(),
                       [](double d1, double d2) { return d1 + d2; });
    });

std::cout << "Column means: ";
std::transform(
    colsums.begin(), colsums.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "),
    [&data](double d) { return d / data.size(); });
```

[LWS Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2bW3X5$1)

Comment: I am using this for_each solution now in `https://github.com/amwink/bias/blob/master/cpp/fastecm/fastecm.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

First let me state that you really should not nest std::vectors.
Apart from that I got some solution which is of course longer than your initial code but that could save in the long run:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> > Data;

struct ColumnElement : boost::iterator_adaptor<ColumnElement,
                                                Data::const_iterator,
                                                const double> {
        int col;

        ColumnElement(int col, const Data::const_iterator &iter)
        : iterator_adaptor(iter), col(col)
        {}
        const double& dereference()const { return (*base())[col]; }
};

struct Column {
        int col;
        const Data *data;

        Column(int col, const Data *data) : col(col), data(data) {}
        ColumnElement begin()const { return ColumnElement(col, data->begin()); }
        ColumnElement end()const { return ColumnElement(col, data->end()); }
        int size()const { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
};

struct Columns : boost::iterator_adaptor<Columns, boost::counting_iterator<int>,
                                        Column, boost::use_default, Column> {
        const Data *data;

        Columns(int col, const Data *data): iterator_adaptor(col), data(data) {}

        Column dereference()const { return Column(*base(), data); }
};

Columns columnsBegin(const Data &data) { return Columns(0, &data); }
Columns columnsEnd(const Data &data) {
        return Columns(data.empty() ? 0 : data.front().size(), &data);
}
```

This could be used in short:

```
double Mean(const Column &d) {
        return std::accumulate(d.begin(), d.end(), 0.0) / d.size();
}

int main() {
        Data data = {   {1, 2, 3},
                        {2, 2, 2},
                        {9, 8, 7}};
        std::vector<double> colMeans(data[0].size());
        std::transform(columnsBegin(data), columnsEnd(data), 
                       colMeans.begin(), Mean);
        std::copy(colMeans.begin(), colMeans.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ","));
        std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I employed some boost functionality to shorten it, but it could be done without boost (however much longer).

The idea was to create an iterator over all columns (called `Columns` just for shortness) and an iterator that iterates over all elements of one column (`ColumnElement`, also shortened, should be better named `ColumnElementIterator`) and `Column` that represents the range of all Elements of one column.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated. I was curious about STL solutions for ease of maintenance and ease of handing code to others. Boost seems very hard to ignore though. In my case -a relatively small number (<500) of relatively long rows (>100,000 elements) in a dense matrix, I'm not sure if a speed gain of a factor 2 [ http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3159 ] weighs up to the extra programming effort. Is nesting vectors really such a bad idea if you know the dimensionality + the dimensions of your data?

Comment: Nesting vectors has several drawbacks (scattered data, possibility of inconsistent sizes, harder access). The usual way for this is to store the data in a `std::vector<double>` and wrap a class around it that maps two (or more) dimensional indices onto the one dimensional index range of the vector. You should have a look at other implementations of matrices. If your code is not for academic purposes (say learning) I would recommend you to have a look at some libraries that fulfill your needs.