# How to define iterator in different directions for N dimensional nested array?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, std

For example I have a 2D array using double as data type.

```
vector<vector<double> > array2D;

 // Set up sizes. (HEIGHT x WIDTH)
array2D.resize(HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
   array2D[i].resize(WIDTH);
```

How could I define iterators that can iterate along row direction for a given column or along column direction for a given row?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post that.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924912/computing-column-sums-of-matrix-vectorvectordouble-with-iterators) might help you on your way.  Do note if you are using a matrix you should probably just get a matrix library.  They have done all this work already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::function for visiting each element ( in column or row ) and enumerator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> TTable;

void enumerateColumn( size_t column, TTable & table, std::function<void( int&, size_t )> op )
{
    for( size_t index = 0; index < table.size(); ++index )
    {
        op( table[index][column], index );
    }
}

void enumerateRow( size_t row, TTable & table, std::function<void( int&, size_t )> op )
{
    auto& row_tab = table[row];
    for ( size_t index = 0; index < row_tab.size(); ++index )
    {
        op( row_tab[index], index );
    }
}

int main()
{
    TTable table =
    {
    { 1,2,3 },
    { 4,5,6 },
    { 7,8,9 }
    };

    std::cout << "Show Column: " << 2 << std::endl;
    enumerateColumn( 2, table, [] ( int& val, size_t index )
    {
        std::cout << "Index: "<< index <<"  Value: "<< val << std::endl;
    } );

    std::cout << "Show Row: " << 1 << std::endl;
    enumerateRow( 1, table, [] ( int& val, size_t index )
    {
        std::cout << "Index: " << index  << "  Value: " << val << std::endl;
    } );


    std::cout << "Change Column: " << 0 << std::endl;
    enumerateColumn( 0, table, [] ( int& val, size_t index )
    {
        val = 10 * ( index + 1 );
    } );

    std::cout << "Change Row: " << 2 << std::endl;
    enumerateRow( 2, table, [] ( int& val, size_t index )
    {
        val = 100 * ( index + 1 );
    } );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Show Column: 2
Index: 0  Value: 3
Index: 1  Value: 6
Index: 2  Value: 9
Show Row: 1
Index: 0  Value: 4
Index: 1  Value: 5
Index: 2  Value: 6
Change Column: 0
Change Row: 2
```

**enumerateColumn** and **enumerateRow** functions visit each value in the request row or column. To achieve this iteration you just have to set desired row/column index. The std::function is called for each column/row value, so you can do any manipulation inside. Using this methods you can "hide" the mechanism of row/column iteration giving only easy access to each row/column element.
After the last 2 manipulations, the result table will have the next values:

```
10  2   3
20  5   6
100 200 300
```